# jvectormap how to Display only 1 country

Tags: jvectormap

Hi i have spend som time with on my project getting jvectormap to show 1 particular country (Denmark). but it will only show all the world. Hope you can help me?

And this is what I try making it do but it still shows the world:

```
$('#map').vectorMap(
{
    map: 'dk_mill', 
    series: 
    { regions: 
        [{ values: gdpData, scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'], normalizeFunction: 'polynomial' }] 
    }, onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){ el.html(el.html()+'(GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
    } 
});
```

Comment: please include code in your question, not screenshots of code

Comment: no, delete that comment and edit your original question. paste the code in there

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have included the **dk_mill.js** file. 
[Denmark map file](http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-dk-mill.js)